# Micro batching in kafka using python

Tags: json, csv, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am developing a kafka based consumer api which reads json data from a topic and write them to a CSV file.

The problem I am facing here is I need to write 4 files for a day at a interval of 6 hours.But my kafka consumer keeps writing to a single file as it's consuming.

How can I implement the particular use case?

Comment: Do you have to use Python? Kafka Connect S3/HDFS sinks already handles this with a TimestampPartitioner

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for the information. I am not allowed to use Hadoop here and supposed to do it with kafka-python actually.

Comment: Also I am using simple csv file to store the data.Using hdfs it would be easier.

Comment: Kafka Connect is bundled as part of Kafka. It's not related to Hadoop. The HDFS client can be used to write to local disk via the `file://` URI

Comment: Alternatively, Spark or Flink could be used to create 6 hour windows of data... My main point is that you'll have to rewrite this windowing logic on your own, and there's better solutions that exist